# Symfony update from 2.1 to 2.2 composer error

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to update my project from symfony 2.1 to 2.2 . I try to update it package by package. When I type `composer.phar update symfony/symfony`, I get the following error:

```
 Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2
- Installation request for symfony/monolog-bundle == 2.1.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle 2.1.x-dev.
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2
- doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0-beta1 requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2.0-beta2,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3.
- doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.2.x-dev requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2.0-beta2,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3.
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3.
- Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.2.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.2.x-dev, doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0-beta1.
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",

        "friendsofsymfony/rest": "0.7.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.9.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.9.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.0.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v1.3.0",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "v2.3",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you change minimum stability to alpha and replace "dev-master" version to exact version with @dev posfix. So the knpmenubundle version will be "2.0.*@dev"

Answer (score 3):

You locked down some of your third-party bundles to a certain tag/version.

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v1.3.0",
```

The `v1.3.0` tag of [this bundle only supports Symfony 2.1.*](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v1.3.0/composer.json#L25).

You will have to go through every single third-party bundle and make sure you are using the right tag/version.

The line above should look like

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v1.3.1",
```

You can see the requirements of the `v1.3.1` tag in the [composer.json of the bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/v1.3.1/composer.json#L25).

You can also use the `dev-master` tag but that can cause issues if you don't plan on upgrading Symfony regularly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I am facing the following error : "The service "jms_serializer.metadata_driver" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine".
In composer.json:
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*@alpha",
"jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.*"

Comment: Did you try without `@alpha`? Are you sure Doctrine is included in `AppKernel.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I changed the composer entry for doctrine bundle to

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*@alpha",
```

because this is the reason why the overall stability flag is set to alpha according to: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-2-0 .

But now I still have this message when updating the packages:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.2.*@alpha -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0-beta1.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2
    - Installation request for bcc/resque-bundle v1.0 -> satisfiable by bcc/resque-bundle v1.0.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0-beta1 requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2.0-beta2,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3.
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3.
```

I really don't get what the actual problem is out of this these error messages.

Comment: I had update issues because of additional bundles. It is necessary to update them too.
Now I'm having issuses with cache:clear 
"The service "jms_serializer.metadata_driver" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine"."